# Can't see the correct logs in the developer console

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, console

My task is to upgrade angular from version 10 to 12. After upgrading and following all the steps I see the following error in the console when launching the application. Unfortunately, it's not clear where exactly this error is coming from as the logs are encrypted.

How can I find out exactly where this error pops up?

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')
    at main.js:1:165605
    at Object._C (main.js:1:165676)
    at template (982.js:1:165355)
    at U_ (main.js:1:110880)
    at vc (main.js:1:109020)
    at Ec (main.js:1:117150)
    at main.js:1:109221
    at vc (main.js:1:109232)
    at Hs.create (main.js:1:162762)
    at Ep.createComponent (main.js:1:158194)
    at X (polyfills.js:1:17687)
    at X (polyfills.js:1:17222)
    at polyfills.js:1:18528
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1:8270)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js:1:176525)
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1:8191)
    at v.runTask (polyfills.js:1:3329)
    at A (polyfills.js:1:10654)
```

Comment: It's in a html template and it is a `.name` expression on any object. More is not possible to say with the given details. Just search `.name` in your projects html files and try if you can figure it out

Comment: What are you compiling your js with? usually there is an option to turn on source mapping if you are in the dev environment